# Error while connecting pyspark to Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, pyspark, oracle-sqldeveloper, apache-spark-sql

I try to make a connection between pyspark and oracle sql, so I could load tables in this way; 
I am using the following code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
import os

spark_config = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Project_SQL")
sc = SparkContext(conf = spark_config)
sqlctx = SQLContext(sc)

os.environ['SPARK_CLASSPATH'] = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\SQL Developer 4.0.1\jdbc\lib.jdbc6.jar"


df = sqlctx.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@<>:<>:<>"
                                   , driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
                                   , dbtable = "account"
                                   , user="...."
                                   , password="...").load()
```

But I get the following error.

```
An error occurred while calling o29.load.:
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Could anyone help me to fix this? Do you think it is because of the firewall?

Comment: can you connect to the database from sqlplus or sql developer? Check your database url , ip, port , login and password details again.